# How to change login from email to mobile number in android app using laravell api?

Tags: php, android, laravel, authentication, mvvm

Is my Android code login request goes from here to specified URL and takes back the response but response always comes false (user credentials are incorrect) when I try to login with mobile number instead of email.

```
   HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("grant_type", "password");
        map.put("username", mobile);
        map.put("password", password.getText().toString());
        map.put("client_secret", BuildConfig.CLIENT_SECRET);
        map.put("client_id", BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID);
        map.put("device_token", SharedHelper.getKey(PasswordActivity.this, "device_token", "No device"));
        map.put("device_id", SharedHelper.getKey(PasswordActivity.this, "device_id", "123"));
        map.put("device_type", BuildConfig.DEVICE_TYPE);
```

And here is my larvell login function

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $tokenRequest = $request->create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $request->all());
    $request->request->add([
        "client_id" => $request->client_id,
        "client_secret" => $request->client_secret,
        "grant_type" => $request->grant_type,
        "code" => '*',
    ]);

    $response = Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);

    $json = (array)json_decode($response->getContent());

    if (!empty($json['error'])) {
        $json['error'] = $json['message'];
    }
    if (empty($json['error'])) {
        if (Auth::attempt(['mobile' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $user = Auth::user()->id;
            if ($user) {
                $accessTokens = DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('user_id', $user->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
                $t = 1;
                foreach ($accessTokens as $accessToken) {
                    if ($t != 1) {
                        DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)->delete();
                        DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('id', $accessToken->id)->delete();
                    }
                    $t++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $update = User::where('mobile', $request->username)->update(['device_token' => $request->device_token, 'device_id' => $request->device_id, 'device_type' => $request->device_type]);
    $response->setContent(json_encode($json));
//        return response()->json($json);
    return $response;


}
```

Comment: The `LoginController` of laravel uses `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait which has a `username` method, you can override it in the controller and change it's return value from `email` to whatever you want to use

Comment: should i also call login function which is in AUTHENTICATESUSERS or just override username() function in LoginController?

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your Login Controller

```
public function username()
    {
        return 'mobile_number';
    }
```